Manually retry failed payment for a subscription using the same card
I am using stripe in my website. I have one question. If payment for subscription cycle fails, can customer retry the payment manually with the same card instead of waiting for the automatic retry? I don't see such an option in customer portal. The only option is to change the payment method. What is the usual approach?

You can expose functionality to offer this yourself using the invoice Pay API by specifying the payment_method: https://docs.stripe.com/api/invoices/pay#pay_invoice-payment_method
Or, the customer can alternatively open the invoice to pay using the hosted invoice page and enter the same details manually.
